# How to Disable Home Button on Android TV Remote

Tags: android, android-homebutton

There are a couple of SO posts that have already discussed similar issues, but I find them not much relevant or too complex. I am working with an Android TV which has a remote controller, and it is supposed to be used in an enterprise environment. Users should not be able to have much control, so I have to restrict some of the functions available on the remote.
I created a simple app that overrides `onKeyDown()` and displays pressed keys using the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    //Read the input and display its code
    switch(keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME:
            mTextView.setText("Home");
            break;
        default:
            char c = event.getDisplayLabel();
            String code = String.valueOf(keyCode);
            String displayText = c + " " + keyCode;
            mTextView.setText(displayText);
            mTextView.setBackgroundColor(mColor^=Color.GREEN);

    }

    return true;
}
```

I am able to capture most of the keys and override their behaviors most notably 131, 132, 133, and 134 (used as Media, TV, Web, and App shortcuts respectively on the remote).
[image]
[image]

The only problem is the Home button which AOSP source code `(KeyEvent.java)` says is system-specific:

```
* This key is handled by the framework and is never delivered to applications. */
    public static final int KEYCODE_HOME            = 3;
```

A solution that struck me was to extend `KeyEvent` and override the method `isSystem()` to return false when the selected key is `KEYCODE_HOME`. But, this method is defined final and I cannot override it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Would 'kiosk' mode be appropriate: https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html

Comment: Thanks @MorrisonChang I am reading. It seems lock mode would work for me.

Comment: Could you please share the model of android TV for this remote control? I'm looking for the key code of menu button

Answer (score 1):

you need to use

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

in your manifest and

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+event.getKeyCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return false;

    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

i think control home key is 3

i hope was helpful